# Restful url through property file

Tags: java, rest, properties, jersey

Hello all i have sample restful service below with jersey 2

MODEL Class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "book")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "id", "name", "author", "price" })
public class Book {

private String id;
private String name;
private String price;
private String author;

public Book() {

}

public Book(String id, String name, String price, String author) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.author = author;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

}
```

My DAOImpl

```
public class BooksImpl{
static Connection conn = null;
static Statement stmt;
ResultSet rs;

public List<Book> getAllBooks() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException {
    getConnection();
    List<Book> arrBook = new ArrayList<Book>();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(GET_ALL_BOOKS);
    while (rs.next()) {
        arrBook.add(new Book(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4)));
    }
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
    return arrBook;
}
```

Service

```
@Path("/library")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8",MediaType.APPLICATION_XML + ";charset=utf-8" })
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8",MediaType.APPLICATION_XML + ";charset=utf-8" })
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {

private BooksImpl booksImpl = new BooksImpl();

@GET
public Response getBooks(@QueryParam("format") String format) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException {
    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(new GenericEntity<List<Book>>(booksImpl.getAllBooks()) {
    }).header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "XML".equalsIgnoreCase(format)
            ? MediaType.APPLICATION_XML + ";charset=UTF-8" : MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8")
            .status(Status.OK).build();

}
```

So finally i make a get request say in a postman like ::

```
http://localhost:8080/BooksJAXRS/library
```

It's good and i can get the reponse by getting all the books from DB.

my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>BooksJAXRS</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.library.books</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My requriment is for different http methods we have different url end point paths for example

```
GET :  http://localhost:8080/BooksJAXRS/library
POST :  http://localhost:8080/BooksJAXRS/library
DELETE : http://localhost:8080/BooksJAXRS/library/1
PUT :  http://localhost:8080/BooksJAXRS/library/1
```

So i make a props file

```
GET=http://localhost:8080/BooksJAXRS/library
POST=http://localhost:8080/BooksJAXRS/library
DELETE= http://localhost:8080/BooksJAXRS/library/1
PUT= http://localhost:8080/BooksJAXRS/library/1
```

Now i want to capture that restful url and pass it through props file and route it accordingly depending on the method and url

Thank you
Mark

Comment: `However i wanted read that url path ... to be read from my properties files when a client hit the url ... to get all books.` - [UriInfo and UriBuilder](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/uris-and-links.html) ?

Comment: @RomanVottner updated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create 2 mappings on 2 different methods that call the same private method like this:

```
@Path("/")
...
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {

    @Path("/")
    @GET
    public Response getBooksByRoot(@QueryParam("format") String format) {
        return getBooks(format);
    }

    @Path("/library")
    @GET 
    public Response getBooksByLibrary(@QueryParam("format") String format) {
        return getBooks(format);
    }

    private Response getBooks(String format) {
        ...
    }

    @Path("/library")
    @POST 
    public Response createBook(@QueryParam("name") String name) {
        ...
    }
```

**Response Update:**

It seems that you want a dynamic mapping, so you need to use a `Path` with a regular expression.

```
@Path("/")
...
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {

    @Path("/{parameter:.*}")
    @GET
    public Response getBooks(@PathParam("parameter") String parameter) {
        if (properties.getProperty("GET").endsWith(parameter) {
            // code to get the books here
        } else {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
        }
    }
```

**WARNING:** The code snippet above is only meant to show the idea, it is not meant to be perfect. For example testing with `endsWith` could not be enough according to your context.

Comment: Thank you.By the way by doing like this does the url will load through properties file?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "load through properties file", could you please clarify?

Comment: I am sorry i will do that. When any client hit my url "http://localhost:8080/BooksJAXRS/library" it should go straight away to my properties file and from that properties file depending upon the url endpoint i.e. a GET request to /library should return all of my books,POST request to /library should create a new book etc

Comment: You simply map a new method with @Path("/library") as path but with also @POST, check my response update

Comment: @mark What is the property used for you want to read upon link invocation? Do you want to read the DB configuration and initialize a new DB connection on every request? This sounds like a veeeeery bad idea. I'm a bit confused by your specification TBH.

Comment: I know thats a bad idea but that was my requirement.What ever request the end user make it should hit the properties file 1st and from there it should read the base path and then depending upon the resource requested example :/getAllBooks,/createbook,/DeleteBook it should be mapped to my service class..  @Roman

Comment: @NicolasFilotto by doing that yes it works but i am not sure it will work with properties file

Comment: sorry I still don't get what you are supposed to do with the properties file, please update your question to add a concrete example because it is still unclear

Comment: sure i will do it now

Comment: whaoo you want a dynamic mapping, this is very bad in term of performances

Comment: Ah yes i agree but thats the actual requirement i need :D

Answer (score 0):

When using standard web descriptor (url-pattern /*) and annotated end-points (@Path /library) there is not so much that can be done for dynamic (at runtime) routing at this points. If you want or need some dynamic routes, one option put the "app" into a new context like:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And add some standard `Servlet` to forward to your desired end-points:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>route</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>my.package.Route</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>route</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

my.package.Route will be get hit on any other than /app/* request and you can do **your** routing to forward the request anywhere.

Comment: it says java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.pack.route